# How to make mean with small numbers in a list

Tags: r, median

I have a list of small numbers :

```
pval.vec <- c(7.777067e-12, 8.345999e-16, 4.341658e-17, 5.984561e-15 ,1.711345e-15)
```

When I apply the mean of this list :

```
cat(sprintf("le mean value est %f",median(pval.vec)))
```

It gives me a result => `0.000000`

I need to have a value with (nbr)e-(exposant)

Comment: cat(sprintf("le mean value est %f",median(pval.vec)))

Comment: So my error is in %f

Comment: Yes. Try something like `sprintf("%8e",median(pval.vec))`. I meant use `%e` instead of `%f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%f` format is for `“fixed point”` decimal notation. Default is `6`. That's why you are getting `0.000000`.

You can try to use `%e` for exponential.

```
 # Data
 pval.vec <- c(7.777067e-12, 8.345999e-16, 4.341658e-17, 5.984561e-15 ,1.711345e-15)

 cat(sprintf("le mean value est %e",median(pval.vec)))
 #le mean value est 1.711345e-15


 #One can specify number of digits after decimal. e.g. for 2 digits
 cat(sprintf("le mean value est %.2e",median(pval.vec)))
 #le mean value est 1.71e-15
```